# Defining XSD (XML Schema) type without a namespace but referring to it with namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Sorry if this question is a bit odd, but I'm new to XSD, and there's a snippet of XSD code I'm failing to understand. The code is below as the question is rather confusing without the code.

The XSD code defines a new Complex Type without a namespace (i.e. the default namespace), but an element definition uses the new type with a namespace. Is this allowed or as my present understanding of namespaces tells me it is not. I thought to use a type in a namespace it must be defined in the same namespace. But maybe if it's defined in the default namespace this is OK?

```
<schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://api.spp.org/schema/mui/Virtual/v2" xmlns:cmn="http://api.spp.org/schema/mui/Common/v4"
xmlns:vt="http://api.spp.org/schema/mui/Virtual/v2">

...

<element name="OfferByRange" type="vt:OfferByRangeType" />

<complexType name="OfferByRangeType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="UseSlope" type="boolean" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
        <element maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="1" name="Point" type="cmn:MWPricePointType">
        </element>
    </sequence>
    <attributeGroup ref="vt:OfferByRangeIdGroup" />
</complexType>

<attributeGroup name="OfferByRangeIdGroup">
    <attribute name="locationName" type="cmn:LocationNameType" use="required" />
    <attribute name="startHour" type="cmn:DatetimeHourType" use="required" />
    <attribute name="stopHour" type="cmn:DatetimeHourType" use="required" />
</attributeGroup>
```

The line `<element name="OfferByRange" type="vt:OfferByRangeType" />` refers to the type `OfferByRangeType` in the namespace `vt`. But the type is not defined in the namespace `vt` making me think this is not allowed? I'm just trying to understand XML namespaces better. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "But the type is not defined in the namespace vt" is that an actual error you're getting or is that you concluding that yourself?

Comment: There is a default namespace with no prefix `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`

Comment: @mamift that is what I concluded myself. This schema works I just don't know how. But the answer is that the target namespace and the vt namespace are the same so it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema defines all elements in the target namespace. Which is defined in the schema tag. As you can see it is the same as the vt namespace. So not only is this correct. It is also the common way to do. Even though most people refer to the target namespace as tns.

If you want to reference your own elements without a prefix (namespace), you can define the default namespace as target namespace like this:

```
xmlns="http://api.spp.org/schema/mui/Virtual/v2"
```

Comment: I see the target namespace and the vt namespace are defined as the same namespace. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

The complex type `OfferByRangeType` - like all the other top-level declarations in the schema document - is in the namespace `http://api.spp.org/schema/mui/Virtual/v2` because that is declared as the target namespace of the schema document. A name appearing in the `name` attribute of a global component is always in the target namespace, but a namespace prefix is needed when referencing the component from elsewhere.